# What was Esau's birthright?

Tags: genesis, esau

**What did Esau's birthright all consist of?**

So in Genesis 25 (NKJV) we see Esau sell off his birthright to Jacob.

> <sup>**29**</sup> Now Jacob cooked a stew; and Esau came in from the field, and he
> was weary. <sup>**30**</sup> And Esau said to Jacob, “Please feed me with that same
> red stew, for I am weary.” Therefore his name was called [g]Edom.
>
> <sup>**31**</sup>But Jacob said, “Sell me your birthright as of this day.”
>
> <sup>**32**</sup> And Esau said, “Look, I am about to die; so what is this birthright
> to me?”
>
> <sup>**33**</sup> Then Jacob said, [h]“Swear to me as of this day.”
>
> So he swore to him, and sold his birthright to Jacob. <sup>**34**</sup> And Jacob
> gave Esau bread and stew of lentils; then he ate and drank, arose, and
> went his way. Thus Esau despised his birthright.

I'm wondering what that birthright was.

I see the concept of the double portion is first mentioned in the Law of Moses.
Deuteronomy 21:17 (NKJV) says that the first born **is given a double portion.**

> <sup>**17**</sup> But he shall acknowledge the son of the unloved wife as the
> firstborn by giving him a double portion of all that he has, for he is
> the beginning of his strength; the right of the firstborn is his.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "one cannot give double of what they own since they don't own it."  Can you elaborate on your question?

This article gives an explanation of the birthright beyond the material assets being inherited:  https://etzion.org.il/en/tanakh/torah/sefer-bereishit/parashat-toldot/toldot-birth-rights

Comment: @diyImma I'll take a look at the article. 

That's why I may be ignorant. How I imagine it is: if you have $5 you can't give away $10.

Comment: the double portion means that if at death the father has $100, the firstborn would inherit $50, while child #2 and #3 would each get $25

Comment: @diyImma ohhhh... So I guess that means that Esau only lost his ability to receive the most from his father?

Comment: Correct.  Though the blessings Isaac gave him afterwards more than made up for the loss of the legal inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The formal blessing of the birthright (usually the oldest son) had several functions:

1. The birthright blessing came with a double portion of inherited land (Gen 48:22, Deut 21:17)
2. The birthright also came with the acknowledgement that this (usually eldest) son would become the priest of the family
3. The birthright also came with the acknowledgement that is son would be the leader of the family
4. For some, this leader responsibility also came with the promise that he would be one of the progenitors of the promised Messiah.